# Printing Appropriate Number Through Array

Tags: java, printing

I'm trying to print out a baseball players on base percentage. So far, the code is going great. The only issue is that when I'm printing out the OBP for each year, I can't seem to match up the correct year that correlates to the year the user input. Each time it loops in the method printOnBasePercentage() it increments the year by one. Is there a way I can resolve this issue? Thanks.

I've tried adding `+startYear++` and that didn't seem to work. It got me closer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numYears;
    double [] years;
    String name;
    int startYear;
    double oBP;

    int hits, walks, sacFlies, hitsByPitch, atBats;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name of baseball player: ");
    name = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of years " + name +" has been playing: ");
    numYears = keyboard.nextInt();

    years = new double[numYears];

    System.out.print("Enter " +name +" first year on the team: ");
    startYear = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int index = 0; index < years.length; index++) {
        System.out.print("For Year: "+ startYear++);

        System.out.print("\nEnter how many hits the player has: ");
        hits = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of walks the player has: ");
        walks = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of sacrifice flies the player has: ");
        sacFlies = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of hits by pitch the player has: ");
        hitsByPitch = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the amount of at bats the player has: "); 
        atBats = keyboard.nextInt();

        years[index] = ((hits + walks + hitsByPitch) / atBats+ walks+ hitsByPitch +sacFlies);  
    }

    printOnBasePercentage(name, startYear, years); 
}

public static void printOnBasePercentage(String name, int startYear, double []years){
    for (int index = 0; index < years.length; index++){

        System.out.println("\n" + name + "'s On Base Percentage");

        System.out.printf("For Year: " +startYear + "   " + "%.3f", years[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that out. It looks like the loop would end after one time printing the printonBasePercentage() method. Didn't seem to print correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use one changeable variable in the both loops. In the main method you increment `startYear` variable and after that you pass this changed variable in the `printonBasePercentage` method. Try to replace this line:

```
System.out.print("For Year: "+ startYear++);
```

by:

```
System.out.print("For Year: "+ startYear + index);
```